# How to remove artefacts from this image?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, image-restoration

There is some vertical banding near the tree trunks in the following image.

[image]

Is there a way remove this type of artefact, preferably using Mathematica?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo no, JPEG artifacts are local to 16x16 pixel blocks. The artifacts in the question appear to follow the trees that are much farther away from the artifacts than that.